Why don't I get a symmetric output from the FFT?
I am working with Vitis Model Composer to compute and implement the FFT of an audio signal. The schematic in use is reported in figure. Specifically, I am working with a transform length of 1024 points, scaling the results by the transform length.

Since I would like to get later the analytic signal, I would be interested in the symmetry of the output signal in order to apply the heaviside function (2U). The problem is that from the output (following figure) there doesn't seem to be any symmetry, and I was wondering if I was doing something wrong or if there was something I am not considering.

In figure, the blue bars indicate the beginning and end of a 1024-point window over which the transform occurs and in which I expect the signal to be symmetrical.
The top plot shows instead the real part while the plot in the middle shows the imaginary part.

looks symmetric to me, if you mean the blue plot... and I hope the large blue lines are signal, not illustration. if they aren't signal, then IDK what you're trying to show. there's nothing to see. -- generally, this question is not debuggable. [mre]. you need to tag the programming language.

@ChristophRackwitz the blue plot shows only the transform length within which I expect simmetry. The signal is the yellow one, the real part at the top plot and the imaginary part at the bottom plot, overlapped to the blue one

Often implementations only show half the Fourier transform, leaving the redundant (because of symmetry) half out.

@CrisLuengo I think I've found the problem...the FFT core implements the butterfly algorithm and from the documentation it seems that the output is "bit reverse", now setting the flag to "natural order" the signal within each window seems symmetric!

Feel free to post an answer then.
